# warning: "MTK_MULTI_STORAGE_SUPPORT" is not defined [-Wundef]

Tags: android, c, makefile, cross-compiling, android-kernel

Hello this warning appears while compiling source code **16 times**

also the zimage it produce is not working

how to define **"MTK_MULTI_STORAGE_SUPPORT"** here is the Warning from log :

```
 In file included from /home/mahmoud/S860_ROW_KK_OpenSource/android/kernel/../mediatek/platform/mt6582/kernel/core/include/mach/devs.h:4:0,
                 from /home/mahmoud/S860_ROW_KK_OpenSource/android/kernel/mediatek/platform/mt6582/kernel/core/mt_devs.c:22:
/home/mahmoud/S860_ROW_KK_OpenSource/android/kernel/../out/target/product/phaeton_row/obj/CUSTGEN/custom/kernel/core/board-custom.h:11:6: warning: "MTK_MULTI_STORAGE_SUPPORT" is not defined [-Wundef]
/home/mahmoud/S860_ROW_KK_OpenSource/android/kernel/../out/target/product/phaeton_row/obj/CUSTGEN/custom/kernel/core/board-custom.h:11:35: warning: "no" is not defined [-Wundef]
```

and here is the file board-custom.h :

```
#ifndef __ARCH_ARM_MACH_MT6575_CUSTOM_BOARD_H
#define __ARCH_ARM_MACH_MT6575_CUSTOM_BOARD_H

#include <generated/autoconf.h>

/*=======================================================================*/

/* MT6575 SD                                                             */

/*=======================================================================*/

#define CFG_DEV_MSDC0

#define CFG_DEV_MSDC1

#if (MTK_MULTI_STORAGE_SUPPORT == no)

#undef CFG_DEV_MSDC1

#endif

//#define CFG_DEV_MSDC2

//#define CFG_DEV_MSDC3

//#define CFG_DEV_MSDC4

#if defined(CONFIG_MTK_COMBO) || defined(CONFIG_MTK_COMBO_MODULE)

/*

SDIO slot index number used by connectivity combo chip:

0: invalid (used by memory card)

1: MSDC1
2: MSDC2

*/
#define CONFIG_MTK_COMBO_SDIO_SLOT  (2) /* MSDC0 for temp use */
#else
#undef CONFIG_MTK_COMBO_SDIO_SLOT
#endif

#if 0 /* FIXME. */
/*=======================================================================*/
/* MT6575 UART                                                           */
/*=======================================================================*/
#define CFG_DEV_UART1
#define CFG_DEV_UART2
#define CFG_DEV_UART3
#define CFG_DEV_UART4

#define CFG_UART_PORTS          (4)

/*=======================================================================*/
/* MT6575 I2C                                                            */
/*=======================================================================*/
#define CFG_DEV_I2C
//#define CFG_I2C_HIGH_SPEED_MODE
//#define CFG_I2C_DMA_MODE

/*=======================================================================*/
/* MT6575 ADB                                                            */
/*=======================================================================*/
#define ADB_SERIAL "E1K"

#endif

/*=======================================================================*/
/* MT6575 NAND FLASH                                                     */
/*=======================================================================*/
#if 0
#define RAMDOM_READ 1<<0
#define CACHE_READ  1<<1
/*******************************************************************************
 * NFI & ECC Configuration 
 *******************************************************************************/
typedef struct
{
    u16 id;         //deviceid+menuid
    u8  addr_cycle;
    u8  iowidth;
    u16 totalsize;  
    u16 blocksize;
    u16 pagesize;
    u32 timmingsetting;
    char devciename[14];
    u32 advancedmode;   //
}flashdev_info,*pflashdev_info;

static const flashdev_info g_FlashTable[]={
    //micro
    {0xAA2C,  5,  8,  256,  128,  2048,  0x01113,  "MT29F2G08ABD",  0},
    {0xB12C,  4,  16, 128,  128,  2048,  0x01113,  "MT29F1G16ABC",  0},
    {0xBA2C,  5,  16, 256,  128,  2048,  0x01113,  "MT29F2G16ABD",  0}, 
    {0xAC2C,  5,  8,  512,  128,  2048,  0x01113,  "MT29F4G08ABC",  0},
    {0xBC2C,  5,  16, 512,  128,  2048,  0x44333,  "MT29F4G16ABD",  0},
    //samsung 
    {0xBAEC,  5,  16, 256,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "K522H1GACE",    0},
    {0xBCEC,  5,  16, 512,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "K524G2GACB",    0},
    {0xDAEC,  5,  8,  256,  128,  2048,  0x33222,  "K9F2G08U0A",    RAMDOM_READ},
    {0xF1EC,  4,  8,  128,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "K9F1G08U0A",    RAMDOM_READ},
    {0xAAEC,  5,  8,  256,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "K9F2G08R0A",    0},
    //hynix
    {0xD3AD,  5,  8,  1024, 256,  2048,  0x44333,  "HY27UT088G2A",  0},
    {0xA1AD,  4,  8,  128,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "H8BCSOPJOMCP",  0},
    {0xBCAD,  5,  16, 512,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "H8BCSOUNOMCR",  0},
    {0xBAAD,  5,  16, 256,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "H8BCSOSNOMCR",  0},
    //toshiba
    {0x9598,  5,  16, 816,  128,  2048,  0x00113,  "TY9C000000CMG", 0},
    {0x9498,  5,  16, 375,  128,  2048,  0x00113,  "TY9C000000CMG", 0},
    {0xC198,  4,  16, 128,  128,  2048,  0x44333,  "TC58NWGOS8C",   0},
    {0xBA98,  5,  16, 256,  128,  2048,  0x02113,  "TC58NYG1S8C",   0},
    //st-micro
    {0xBA20,  5,  16, 256,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "ND02CGR4B2DI6", 0},

    // elpida
    {0xBC20,  5,  16, 512,  128,  2048,  0x01123,  "04GR4B2DDI6",   0},
    {0x0000,  0,  0,  0,    0,    0,     0,        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 0}
};
#endif


#define NFI_DEFAULT_ACCESS_TIMING        (0x44333)

//uboot only support 1 cs
#define NFI_CS_NUM                  (2)
#define NFI_DEFAULT_CS              (0)

#define USE_AHB_MODE                    (1)

#define PLATFORM_EVB                (1)

#endif /* __ARCH_ARM_MACH_MT6575_CUSTOM_BOARD_H */
```

Comment: in the ProjectConfig.mk
`MTK_MULTI_STORAGE_SUPPORT = no`

Comment: why there is no help on that issue